# Add confirmation for saving a tag's syntax highlighting change

Tags: feature-request, tags, moderator-tools, syntax-highlighting

♦ moderators have the ability to assign to every tag a default language for syntax highlighting (see the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/295232)):

[image]

When clicking the Save button, all that happens is that the button gets disabled, which is easily missed. Could we get a popup/banner that the change has been saved, just like for instance saving profile changes?